# Fix PNG transparancy IE

Tags: jquery, png, transparency

I've read multiple posts, but I'm wondering, how do I fix every PNG transparency on my page for IE so it doesn't render things horribly.

Also, I'm using gradient backgrounds with css, but when I load the page with IE it asks me if I want to run the "active x content as it may be harmful?" how can I tell it to not do this and just load the page?

Answer (score 0):

Just to know, that's not something related with jQuery at all.

---

That's a common issue on IE. You will need to use this `.zip` with resources to fix PNG transparency.

Please read documentation and take a look at the online demo.

This is an improved version.

**Download link:**

http://www.twinhelix.com/test/iepngfix.zip

**Documentation and demo here:**

http://www.twinhelix.com/css/iepngfix/demo/

---

Hope this helps :-)